# JPA Criteria API using ISNULL in a order by statement

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I use MySQL 5.5 with Hibernate 3.6 and JPA 2.0. I have a User table with a firstName which could also be null or an empty string. I want to have those empty firstName results last in my search results. For that I wrote the following SQL query which works just fine:

```
SELECT * FROM User ORDER BY ISNULL(firstName), firstName = "", firstName ASC LIMIT 100
```

Now want to translate this to JPA using the criteria API and I am not quite so sure about the order by. Here is what I have:

```
criteriaQuery = criteriaQuery.orderBy(cb.asc(cb.isNull(users.get(User_.firstName))), cb.asc(cb.equal(users.get(User_.firstName), "")), cb.asc(users.get(User_.firstName)));
```

However, the code snippet above does not work, because the CriteriaBuilder.isNull() method is traslated to IS NULL and not to the ISNULL() function of MySQL. I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: is null
```

Any ideas on how to check for null in the Order by statement with JPA 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible. In JPA you can `ORDER BY` fields only that you select (that are in the `SELECT` part of your query). The problem is that there is no IS_NULL function, that can be used in the `SELECT` part.

Comment: So is there another way to place the null and empty strings entries at the bottom of the result with JPA criteria API

Comment: I see one solution: NativeQueries.

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same problem as you do, finally I solve it using this way, maybe you can try:

```
  CriteriaQuery<> query;
  query.orderBy(cb.desc(cb.selectCase().
when(cb.isNull("field name"),0).otherwise(1)),
cb.asc("field name");
```

Answer (score 0):

JPA can only order field name, so you must declare a new column with your sort expression as below.

```
SELECT u, (firstName is null) as firstName_isNull 
FROM User u 
ORDER BY firstName_isNull , firstName = "", firstName ASC
```